# How do you use the map function in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm trying to understand how `.map` works and all of my searches are returning examples that aren't helping me resolve my issue. From my understanding `.map` is a cleaner way of performing a **for-in** loop, the only difference is that `.map` <strike>replaces your original</strike> *creates a new* array and **for-in** just alters your original arrays values.

### Attempt

In the code example below, I'm expecting the `.map` function to replace my **wheels** array with new **Tire** objects whose **state** properties are all set to `.Flat`.

This is a *playground-ready* version of what I'm trying to accomplish in my program:

```
enum State {
    case Ok, Flat
}

class Tire {

    var state = State.Ok

    init(t: State) {
        state = t
    }
}

var wheels = [Tire(t: .Ok), Tire(t: .Ok), Tire(t: .Ok)]

wheels = wheels.map { $0.state = .Flat }
```

### Result

> error: cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'Tire'
>   wheels = wheels.map { $0.state = .Flat }
>                         ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~

### Question

In the given situation, how can I set all of my **Tire** objects states to `.Flat` using `.map`?

Comment: Would be interesting to hear the rational behind the downvote. This question conforms to [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `$0.state = .Flat` is an assignment. It does not return a value. Try this:

```
wheels = wheels.map { w in
    w.state = .Flat
    return w
}
```

`map` does not replace anything. It *projects* each element from your array to a new array by applying the transformation block. You can choose to assign this new array to the old array, but otherwise it will not alter the original array.

Comment: thank you, this was exactly the example I needed. Also, thanks for correcting my understanding.

Comment: It's important to note that `w.state = .Flat` does *not* change the value of any of the wheels in the `wheels` array (the `w` is a copy of each wheel in turn.) The above could be accomplished more simply by: `wheels = wheels.map { Wheel(t: .Flat) }`

Comment: @DanielT.: *"w.state = .Flat does not change the value of any of the wheels"* is wrong here because  `class Tire` is a *reference type*. – The statement *"... but otherwise it will not alter the original array."* is correct because the array itself is not changed, but perhaps misleading because the referenced objects *are changed*.

Comment: Try `let newWheels : [Tire] = wheels.map { w in w.state = .Flat ; return w } ; print(wheels.map { $0.state } )`

Comment: @MartinR Good catch. I'm so used to dealing with structs I didn't notice that Wheel was a class.

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 similar key functions which perform similar operations, the basic purpose of which is to take an array and build another array from it:

func  map(transform:(R)->T) -> [T] --- Map takes an array of elements of one type and converts it to an array of elements of (potentially) another type, by calling a transform function on each element in turn.  So you can convert an array of Int's to an array of strings:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map { "\($0)" } // --> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

func  filter(predicate:(T)->Boolean) -> [T] -- Filter takes an array of elements and converts it to an array of elements of the same type, but only includes those elements for which predicate returns true.  So you can filter an array of ints to leave only the even numbers:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].filter { $0 % 2 == 0 } // --> [ 2, 4]
```

There are other variants, such as `flatMap` which takes [[T]] and turns it into [T] by iterating over the input and array and appending the contents of each array to an output array:

```
[ [1, 2], [3, 4]].flatMap() // --> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It's also worth nothing that the concept behind `map` is that, in simplistic terms, it can be used to map any input type to an output type, so you can define:

```
func <R, T> map(in:R?, transform:(R)->T) -> T?
```

for example, which would translate any optional input type into an optional output type given a function that translates the base type.